# GWT Layout Changing issues when using back button with PlaceHistoryMapper

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Is anybody else running into this - i can't seem to find any information on it and it's not consistent

we're running into a bug in GWT (using places/activities and a place history mapper) - occasionally when pressing the back button the entire layout gets shifted to the left

i have a docklayout panel as my main panel - it's center panel is the content panel and the left side of it is the navigation panel (similar to the GWT showcase), occasionally it will happen where the navigation panel stays fine but the entire content panel is shifted to the left (with cell tables and data grids, it pushes into the navigation panel and we can't read half the data)

any input is greatly appreciated